# Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ict136/viewcart.php on line 52 this is the error?

Tags: arrays, string, session

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT cart_id, productname, cart.prod_id AS productnumber,
   user_id, cart.quant, product.productprice * cart.quant AS tot_price

    FROM cart 

   JOIN product ON cart.prod_id = product.productnumber

   WHERE   customernumber='.$_SESSION('customernumber').' AND flag = 0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

$query= mysql_query("SELECT cart_id, productname, cart.prod_id AS productnumber, user_id, cart.quant, product.productprice * cart.quant AS tot_price
    FROM cart 
   JOIN product ON cart.prod_id = product.productnumber
   WHERE   customernumber='".$_SESSION['customernumber']."' AND flag = 0");